# Joda time library with Grails 4

Tags: grails, jodatime, grails-4

I am trying to migration from grails 3.4.x to grails 4.1.0

We have used joda-time library and have domains with DateTime and other joda classes.

On version Grails 3.4, we did date mapping like

```
grails.gorm.default.mapping = {
    "user-type" type: org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime, class: org.joda.time.DateTime
    "user-type" type: org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate, class: org.joda.time.LocalDate
    "user-type" type: org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime, class: org.joda.time.LocalDateTime
}
```

On grails v4, this doesn't work and takes forever and ended up with GC exceed limit error (I have event tried to increased the memory to 2G, but same issue).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**Update:**
Grails 4 has good support for java.time library. One solution is to replace the joda library but this will effect whole application and lot of changes.